# The difference between wa and ga

Tags: grammar, particles, は-and-が

I am aware that both are to be but i have trouble figuring out which one is appropriate for which sentence. Would one be for stating a fact about oneself and the other be for an action？

Comment: No vote rights, but looks like a duplicate to me (Assuming he is pronouncing correctly は　が

Comment: People have already spent hours trying to explain this. Using Google, I found: on _japanese.stackexchange.com_ : [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C) and on _japanese.about.com_ : [Particles: Wa vs. Ga](http://japanese.about.com/library/weekly/aa051301a.htm)